# How do I structure this new logic to fit into pre-existing code?

Tags: javascript

I have written a code that removes all consonants before a vowel from a string and replaces it with an 'r' and in the case, the string starts with a vowel it should return the word without doing anything to it. Now, I want to add two things I came up with to it but unfortunately, I have not been able to:
1. When the string input is all consonants then it should do nothing and just return the string.
2. If user types in space like so '              ' then it should be trimmed.
 How do I place this logic in the code below without affecting what is already working?

```
const scoobyDoo = str => {
    if(typeof str !== 'string'){
        return 'This function accepts strings only';
    }
    let newStr = str.toLowerCase().split('');
    let arrWord = newStr.length;
    let regex = /[aeiou]/gi;
        if (newStr[0].match(regex)){
            let nothing = newStr.join('');
            return nothing;
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < arrWord; i++){
                let vowelIndex = newStr.indexOf(str.match(regex)[i].toLowerCase());
                newStr.splice(0, vowelIndex, 'r');
                return newStr.join('');
            }
        }
    }
console.log(scoobyDoo('scooby'));//works as expected returns 'rooby'
console.log(scoobyDoo('ethane'));//works as expected returns 'ethane'
console.log(scoobyDoo('why'));// should return 'why'
console.log(scoobyDoo('          '));// should return trimmed space and a 
text telling the user only spaces were entered.
```

Comment: one easy way to do it is to separate each distinct part of operations into a separate function and then have your main one call them in sequence. You can then very easily verify each separate piece works individually, since they won't be complex by themselves and will have very clear goals and simple logic instead of puzzling why your giant piece of code stops working.

Comment: unfortunately, this reads less like a question and more like a request to implement a requirements list.

Comment: I agree with vlaz. I'd go with something like if (!needsChange (str) ) { return str } else { str = trimSpaces(str); str = replaceVowels(str); } and then, write each of those functions separately.

Comment: @vlaz@Victoria Ruiz thankyou. I once did something as that but it didn't produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this doesn't really answer your question, but your existing logic is very complicated and you could achieve the same result with `String.trim`, `.toLowerCase` and `.replace`:

```
console.log('scooby'.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/^(?=.*?[aeiou])[^aeiou]+/, 'r'))
rooby   
console.log('ethane'.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/^(?=.*?[aeiou])[^aeiou]+/, 'r'))
ethane
console.log('why'.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/^(?=.*?[aeiou])[^aeiou]+/, 'r'))
why
console.log('*' + '      '.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/^(?=.*?[aeiou])[^aeiou]+/, 'r') + '*')
**
```

The regexp uses a positive lookahead to ensure that there is a vowel in the string, and if so replaces all leading consonants with an r.

To do something more in line with your existing function, you could try this. It still makes extensive use of regex functions though.

```
const scoobyDoo = str => {
    if(typeof str !== 'string'){
        return 'This function accepts strings only';
    }
    // is it a blank string?
    if (str.match(/^\s+$/)) {
       return '';
    }
    // does it start with a vowel? if so, nothing to do
    if (str.match(/^[aeiou]/i)) {
       return str;
    }
    // does it only contain consonants?
    if (!str.match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
       return str;
    }
    // must not start with a vowel but still include one
    return str.replace(/^[^aeiou]+/i, 'r');
}
```

Comment: thankyou. I actually do plan to delve into regExps because I realised its power while solving this question and this particular one you just posted caters for almost all user inputs(that I tested it with). However, I am just curious about how to implement it with the logic above.

Comment: I've added another routine more along the lines of what you wrote, but I can't bring myself to do things the hard way!

Comment: you just answered what i was thinking about how to add return statements to the regex. Thankyou and hopefully i won't have to do things the hard way in the future☺